# O que é um autômato celular?

Tags: terminologia, autômatos

Do que se trata o autômato celular? Que tipo de problema isso pode resolver? É algo equivalente às [máquinas de Turing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158043/35406)?

Comment: O jogo da vida é Turing Completo, mas nem todos são. Mais sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101683/64969

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Do que se trata o autômato celular?**

A primeira definição de [Automato Celular](http://www.unz.org/Pub/NewmanJames-1957v04-02070) Surgiu com Von Neumman nos anos 40
 com a intenção de fornecer informações sobre os requisitos lógicos de uma Máquina
 autorreplicadora, e foi usado no [construtor universal de Von
 Neumann](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construtor_universal_de_Von_Neumann).

Em uma definição geral, [Autômato Celular](https://www.ppgee.ufmg.br/defesas/335M.PDF), matematicamente falando , é um arranjo de maquinas de estados que há alterações entre si baseando-se em condições pré-estabelecidas.

> O AC é composto por um conjunto de células com determinados valores, que interagem
>   entre si em função de uma coleção finita de condições pré-definidas. Os estados(valores) das células são alterados conforme um conjunto de regras de transição, que
>   depende da vizinhança (às vezes da própria célula também), ou seja, das células em
>   torno da célula que será atualizada.

Vale Ressalva sobre o trecho **coleção finita de condições pré-definidas**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Evolução de um autómato celular numa rede de dimensão
>   1 e numa rede de dimensão 2 com simetria hexagonal. A regra de
>   interacção é a mesma para os dois autómatos: o estado de cada nó
>   no tempo 1 só depende dos estados nos nós vizinhos no tempo 0

Vamos pegar como referência os autômatos unidimensionais, Temos exatamente 256 regras definidas:

> Cada célula pode assumir um dos possíveis estados (valores) k do
>   conjunto Q, sendo que os estados variam de 0 até k − 1.

Por ser unidimensional, terá apenas dois caminhos(comumente chamado vizinhos), um para direita e um para a esquerda(desconsiderando o próprio ponto k)

> A
>   quantidade possível de combinações com os dois vizinhos e a própria célula e dois
>   estados é 2³ = 8 combinações, sendo que as células terão apenas um dos dois estados
>   existentes, ou seja, o número 2 corresponde a quantidade de estados possíveis que a
>   célula pode assumir, por exemplo 0 ou 1, e o número 3 corresponde a quantidade de
>   vizinhos, isto é, o vizinho da esquerda, a própria célula e o vizinho da direita, o que
>   implica em uma faixa de vizinhança igual a r = 1. Com estas 8 possíveis combinações
>   pode-se formar um total de 2⁸ = 256 regras locais, ou seja, para cada combinação a célula que será atualizada pode receber 0 ou 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em suma os ACs representam determinados conjuntos  que irá sofrer alteração por regras estabelecidas e isso implica na resposta da segunda pergunta:

> ** Que tipo de problema pode resolver?**

Por demonstrar os resultados a partir de regras os ACs são utilizados para simular fenômenos, é possível simular a propagação de um incêndio caso estejamos numa seca forte e o vento estiver a 10 nós para oeste, por exemplo, logicamente a parte ao leste do inicio estaria muito menos, ou não haveria nenhum foco de fogo e a parte queimando quando acabasse com as arvores e/ou encontrasse alguma região de muita rocha se findaria o incêndio.

> **É algo equivalente às máquinas de Turing?**

Semelhante, mas não equivalente. Enquanto os Acs trabalhariam com valores pré definidos de conjuntos **Finitos**, se assemelhando a Fita da máquina, porém para Turing havia um potencial ilimitado de fitas.

> é uma máquina capaz
>   de calcular todos os processos ou funções que sejamos
>   capazes de imaginar

Esta pergunta define bem o significado da Máquina de Turing
[O que é Máquina de Turing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158043/o-que-%C3%A9-a-m%C3%A1quina-de-turing)

Outras referências :
[Autômatos Celulares, máquina de Turing ou a natureza Como máquina de Cálculo](http://200.17.137.109:8081/xiscanoe/Members/andrecaetano/12-1.pdf)